# Has anyone been able to get google login working with javascript or REST with backendless 3.0 stand alone server

Tags: javascript, backendless

I am trying to find out if the anyone has successfully got google authentication to work with 3.0 version of Backendless Standalone using their javascript SDK or directly using their REST API?

If you have, what standalone version of backendless are you running and what if any configuration changes did you need to make?

Backendless support several social authentication provides: twitter, facebook, and google.

I am not able to get the google authentication working with javascript or REST API using backendless provided examples. The javascript/REST examples do work against the current cloud version. I am able to use google authentication with their JAVA SDK with the standalone. I have not tried iOS yet.

[Backendless](https://backendless.com/products/) offers a cloud Mobile backend as a service (MBaaS) platform. Last year they [offered version 3 as a stand alone product](https://backendless.com/standalone-backendless-v-3-0-is-available/) that you could run on your own equipment. I am using the [bitnami linux VM image for backendless](https://bitnami.com/stack/backendless/virtual-machine) version 3.0.0-27 .

Comment: I hate the downvote with no comment because provide no information to improve in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To get the javascript method loginWithGooglePlus using Backendless Javascript [SDK 3.1.23](https://github.com/Backendless/JS-SDK/blob/v3.1.23/libs/backendless.js) to work with Backendless Standalone version 3.X you need to make the following two changes.

1. Change SDK method _loginSocialin in the backendless.js file - the standalone Backendless.serverURL end with /api but e.origin is only the hostname, so **if (e.origin == Backendless.serverURL)** will never be true.

**From**

```
_loginSocial: function(socialType, fieldsMapping, permissions, 
async, container, stayLoggedIn) {
.
.            
Utils.addEvent('message', window, function(e) {
  if (e.origin == Backendless.serverURL) {
    var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

**To**

```
_loginSocial: function(socialType, fieldsMapping, permissions, 
async, container, stayLoggedIn) {
.
.            
Utils.addEvent('message', window, function(e) {
  var pathArray = Backendless.serverURL.split("/");
  var protocol = pathArray[0];
  var host = pathArray[2];
  var url = protocol + '//' + host;
  if (e.origin == url) {
    var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

2. Add the following to the backendless.config file

   ```
   <social>
     <google-plus>    
       <service>
         <authUrl>http[s]://yourhostname/api/users/social/googleplus/authorize</authUrl>
       </service>
     </google-plus>
   </social>
   ```